# Insert image and text in MSWord using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

Well I am trying Word automation in C#.Now I am trying to insert an Picture in the Word along with text to its right.However I am not able to do so because as i add my picture the cursor moves to next location that is beneath the picture .Till now my code is as follows

```
 Word._Application oWord;
        Word._Document oDoc;

        oWord = new Word.Application();
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing); //Add Blank sheet to Word App
        oWord.Visible = true;

      //I have Copied Image 
   oWord.Selection.Paste();
    //I want these text to be added to the right of the image however they appear on the next line
   oWord.Selection.TypeText("A");
   oWord.Selection.TypeText("B");
   oWord.Selection.TypeText("C");
   oWord.Selection.TypeText("D");
```

I tried using Table Method I tried to insert a table with One Row and Two COolumns .The First Row shall save the Picture and the other Row may store the text

```
oDoc.Tables.Add(NewRange, 1, 2, ref defaultTableBehavior, ref autoFitBehavior);
         Word.Table tbl = oDoc.Tables[1];
         oWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdChart);

         tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text="A".PadLeft(10,' ').PadRight(50,' ')+"1.38"
             + Environment.NewLine + "B".PadRight(50,' ')+"1.90"
             + Environment.NewLine + "C".PadRight(55,' ')+"-0.70"
             + Environment.NewLine + "D".PadRight(55,' ')+"0.50";
```

However its a very tenuous task.My data may contain huge values,and if it did this method might be cumbersome
I would really appreciate if someone could provide me with much simpler approach

Comment: Is it mandatory you do this through Com? Via Open XML SDK this is a breeze.

Comment: I am afraid I can only use **COM**